# Pregunta sobre un ejercicio con estructuras de datos

Tags: java, eclipse

Hola me piden hacer este ejercicio en java neon utilizando la estructura que se mas apropiada(pila, cola, colecciones,conjuntos, mapas):

[image: Ejercicio]

Estoy teniendo problemas al hacer el punto B ya que me tira un error el metodo "buscarPoblacion" y no se me ocurre como podria hacer para que segun un pais y una ciudad dada me de su poblacion, tampoco estoy seguro si usar un treemap es la opcion mas indicada para hacer este ejercicio, escucho sugerencias.
Aca el codigo:

```
public class Ciudad {

    private String nombre;
    private String pais;

    public Ciudad(String nombre, String pais){
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.pais = pais;

    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Pais:"+pais+",Ciudad:"+nombre;

    }

}

public class Aplicacion {

    private Map<Integer, Ciudad> poblacionDeCiudades;

    public Aplicacion(){

        poblacionDeCiudades = new TreeMap<Integer,Ciudad>();



    }

    public void agregarCiudad(int poblacion,Ciudad ciudad){
        poblacionDeCiudades.put(poblacion, ciudad);

    }

    public String buscarCiudadPorPoblacion(int poblacion){
        return poblacionDeCiudades.get(poblacion).toString();


    }

    public int buscarPoblacion(String pais, String ciudad){
        int poblacion = -1;

        Set<Integer> p = poblacionDeCiudades.keySet();
        for(Integer numero:p){

            if((poblacionDeCiudades.get(p).toString()).equalsIgnoreCase("Pais:"+pais+",Ciudad:"+ciudad)){

                poblacion = numero;


            }


        }


        return poblacion;




    }


}
```

Comment: estas usando como key la poblacion? o sea que dos ciudades con la misma poblacion... van a parar a donde? no deberias usar ciudad-pais?? (que es lo que se supone que no se repite).. y no se si un treemap es la mejor opcion... como no se, como optimizarias las dos cosas, salvo que uses una DB e indices por las dos.. porque de otra forma, no se puede ordenar por tamaño y nombre al mismo tiempo...

Comment: supuse que no se iban a repetir poblaciones sino no se me ocurria como hacerlo

Comment: la pregunta aca.. es.. que te impide usar dos tipos de estructuras distintas? suponer nunca es bueno...

Comment: La verdad lo hize asi porque es la unica forma que se me ocurrio, como me recomendas hacerlo?

Comment: no no.. el treemap puede llegar a ser tu solucion, lo que seguro no es clave es la poblacion...

Comment: Pero el ejercicio en el punto A me pide que al recorrerlo tiene que estar ordenado primero por las de mayor poblacion

Comment: Y el b te pide exactamente lo contrario.

Comment: entonces podrias mostrarme como seria el codigo? la verdad no entiendo :s

Comment: Usa dos mapas. Uno q tenga como clave la poblacion y otro q tenga como clave la ciudadpais. Y busca en el q te convenga segun lo q pide. Y los dos mapas apuntan a los mismos objetos (no los llenes con objetos distintos)

Comment: Muchas gracias gbianchi, voy a intentar hacerlo

Comment: Tenes la mitad listo. Proba la otra mitad y si algo falla veni a preguntarlo

Comment: Dos mapas lo considero innecesario. Creo que uno con la clave pais-ciudad es más que suficiente, el resto es trabajar sobre la estructura.